# Python UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clients' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
clients = []    
def disconnect_client ():
        for c in clients:
            c['conn'].close()
        clients = []
```

I have this code in python but it gives me that error when i call the function. Where did it go wrong ?

I also have this function and it does not have cause any problems. (it uses the clients variable). Please disregard the comments in my code

```
def start_server ():
    # pornim serverul de socket. parametrii default: AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0
    s = socket.socket()

    # legam portul 8001 de serverul de socket
    s.bind(('', 8001))

    # definim numarul maxim de conexiuni in asteptare
    s.listen(5)
    threading.Thread(target = server_commands).start()
    # facem serverul sa ruleze continuu
    while 1:
        # asteptam o conexiune la server
        # se vor returna 2 valori, un obiect de tip socket (clientul) care se va pune in variabila conn, si adresa clientului care va fi pusa in variabila addr
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connection from:', addr
        # punem obiectul intr-un array pentru a tine evidenta
        clients.append({'conn': conn, 'addr': addr})

        # pornim un nou thread pentru fiecare client pentru a putea accepta o noua conexiune
        # ii dam ca parametrii functia cu care va rula si parametrii dati functiei, in acest caz ii pasam obiectul client si adresa sa
        threading.Thread(target = handle, args = (conn, addr)).start()
```

Comment: `clients` is a local variable to `diconnect_client` function and inside it you are not referencing the `clients` you defined as a list outside it...

Comment: In `disconnect_client` add `global client` so python knows that you don't want a local variable shadowing the global.

Comment: Is `clients` only defined on the first block of code you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to rebind `clients` which means that Python thinks it's a local variable and so can't see global one of the same name.

You can solve the problem by clearing clients inside your function like this:

```
clients[:] = []
```

Mutates the existing list instead of rebinding it.

Answer (score 0):

`clients` is not defined within `disconnect_client`. It is defined outside the scope of the function. Define it within disconnect_client or pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this to run and to re-bind the clients variable, you can use the global keyword:

```
clients = []    
def disconnect_client ():
    for c in clients:
        c['conn'].close()
    global clients
    clients = []
```

But it would actually be much more sensible, as @brito suggested, to just pass it in and then return it:

```
clients = []    
def disconnect_client (clients):
    for c in clients:
        c['conn'].close()
    clients = []
    return clients
```

also I have no idea why you're using eight spaces for the first indentation.

Interestingly, this is a slightly wonky error.  I've never seen it before, but I'd have expected it to throw an error that explicitly informed you that you're trying to re-bind a global variable, which is what the problem is --- because of course the function ordinarily can find a global variable if a variable with the given name doesn't exist in the local scope; it's only when you then try to re-bind it that it causes problems.

Comment: i'm using the tab key